# Trying to use query to colorize images on hover. Two problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to use query to make Black and White images get color on hover. It works, but I have two problems. First, it´s a double pageload, where the colorimages first show, then on second load it shows the black and white.

Second, I have a fixed menu, and the active colored image displays over the menu. I have tried to fiddle with a greater z-index on the menu, to no avail.

Site: www.svenssonsbild.se

This is the script:

```
// On window load. This waits until images have loaded which is essential
$(window).load(function(){

    // Fade in images so there isn't a color "pop" document load and then on window load
    $(".attachment-full").fadeIn(500);

    // clone image
    $('.attachment-full').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"998","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
            el.dequeue();
        });
        this.src = grayscale(this.src);
    });

    // Fade image 
    $('.attachment-full').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    })
    $('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    });     
});

// Grayscale w canvas method
function grayscale(src){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = src;
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height; 
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0); 
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```